# Is prescription heroin (under Dr.'s supervision) in Canada, helping those addicted taper off of it?

Tags: addiction, drug-tapering-weaning, opioids-opiates, heroin

[Prescription heroin gets green light in Canada](http://www.cnn.com/2016/09/14/health/prescription-heroin-canada/), and I was wondering if this **is to help addicts slowly wean themselves off of it under the watchful eye of a Dr.?** *Is that the goal?* If so, are there any statistics showing how effective this route of prescription has been in weaning addicts off of heroin? Or is it more along the lines of "Well... if they are going to continue to use heroin anyhow... they might as well do so under the safety and watchful eye of a doctor?"

In Kentucky, [Overdose cases spike in Louisville: 52 calls in 32 hours](http://www.cnn.com/2017/02/11/health/overdoses-spike-in-louisville/), and they administer antidotes to the heroin overdoses (as I assume elsewhere in the USA), but do studies from Canada's approach have data that indicates prescription Heroin would reduce the risk of heroin overdose? Or is it too early to tell?